# Why can't I switch virtual terminal now?

Tags: linux, xorg, chvt

I have noticed I can't lock the screen because of `vlock` hangs.

`chvt` also hangs on `VT_WAITACTIVE` and only attempts to switch the terminal (I see the image blinking).

Pressing keys that in usually switches VT in text mode (Alt+arrows, Alt+Fx) also makes Xorg picture blink and hide cursor for a second.

The keyboard input also flows to text console in addition to Xorg. I noticed a stray session at tty2. I can log in to tty2 without leaving Xorg:

```
# ps aux | grep qwjerewqr
vi       27051  0.0  0.0   3644  1144 tty2     S+   20:38   0:00 grep qwjerewqr
root     27053  0.0  0.0   3644  1236 pts/27   SN+  20:38   0:00 grep qwjerewqr
```

So,

1. What may have caused this?
2. How do I bring the system back to normal without rebooting (or restarting X applications)?
3. Shall I report a bug report somewhere?

Update: Finally just rebooted it (because of other unrelated problem).